# Classification in SVM

Tags: svm

I am not expert in this area so please bare with me. As far as I know the SVM is used for distinguishing or classifying two sets. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to classify more than two sets or the two is the limit?
2. So far I've seen examples where two sets are separated by line, is it possible to separate sets using another curve e.g. quadratic, sine etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, it is possible to classify more than two classes using Multiclass Kernel-based Vector Machines. [This](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume2/crammer01a/crammer01a.pdf) paper explains well about this.
2. There are non-linear separations as well like radial and polynomial. For more detailed information please refer this [guide](http://web.mit.edu/6.034/wwwbob/svm-notes-long-08.pdf)

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you for reply, do you also know about some practical materials (python or R would be fine) that could help beginner?